# Is it possible to have a foreach statement specified for an element of params Func<T>

Tags: c#, .net, parameters

Is it possible to achieve something like this:

```
Process(
    () => InstanceA.PropertyA,
    () => InstanceB.PropertyB,
    () => InstanceC.List.Select(x => x.PropertyC) // obviously not a proper way to do it
);
```

The third line would replace:

```
foreach(var item in InstanceC.List)
{
    Process(() => item.PropertyC);
}
```

Last part:

```
Process(params Func<object>[] args) // body is in this case irrelevant
```

So, is there a nifty *syntactic sugar* that I've could use to *yield* the inner elements of a list back to the outer `params` argument? Or did I went a step too far?

Comment: If InstanceC was a List<T> type there is a .ForEach() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No but you can concatenate if you really want them to be in the same list.

```
var firstTwo = new Func<object>[] 
{ 
  () => InstanceA.PropertyA, 
  () => InstanceB.PropertyB 
};
Process(firstTwo.Concat(InstanceC.List.Select(x => () => x.PropertyC).ToArray());
```

This evaluates `InstanceC.List` earlier than your code and may not be your intention.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like this.  Haven't compiled it, this may not work.

```
Process( (new List<Func<Object>> {
    () => InstanceA.PropertyA,
    () => InstanceB.PropertyB }).Union( 
      InstanceC.List.Select(x => new Func<Object>(() => x.PropertyC))
    ).ToArray()
);
```

EDIT: Fixing up the syntax as I re-read it...

Comment: I was really hopeful that `x => () => x.Something` syntax would work :)

Comment: again, I don't have a compiler in front of me (I'm on Linux at the moment) but I don't think type inference will figure the delegate type out in this case.